# rewriterule how to handle no ending slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect anything coming into a directory to another. the rewriterule command I use is :

```
RewriteRule ^VirtualDirectory(.*)$ GENS/RealDirectory$1 [L,NC]
```

The thing is that I'd like that a query with no end slash to VirtualDirectory to be rewritten as if the query was for VirtualDirectory/

The behaviour I get is :

query to VirtualDirectory/ works great without the user noticing
query to VirtualDirectory workd great but the url shown in the brwoser is : GENS/RealDirectory/

I've tried many things but I can't get the behaviour I want.

If I add a rule

```
RewriteRule ^VirtualDirectory$ GENS/RealDirectory/ [L,NC]
```

to handle that specific case, it works great except that all resources of the page are rewrited to the folder before VirtualDirectory

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the internal rewrite is happening without a trailing slash, then mod_dir takes over and does a browser redirect to the same URL but with a trailing slash. You can turn off mod_dir by using `DirectorySlash Off` in your .htaccess file. If you want the trailing slash always, try changing the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^VirtualDirectory/?(.*)$ GENS/RealDirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
`DirectorySlash Off` triggers a Internal Server Error
If I comment it and use the rule you provided, the rewriting works great but only for the webpage. All ressources (pictures, ...) are rewrited(?) to http://www.mywebsite.fr/myhtaccessDirectory/ instead of http://www.mywebsite.fr/myhtaccessDirectory/GENS/RealDirectory